# htaccess subfolders silent redirect based on how many subfolders the url/link has

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I have the following situation

Main website `https://www.example.com`

I want:

1. every `https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/` to silent redirect to `https://www.example.com/folder1/index.php?d2=folder2&d3=folder3`
2. every `https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/` to silent redirect to `https://www.example.com/folder1/secondindex.php?d2=folder2&d3=folder3&d4=folder4`

I created a .htaccess file in `https://www.example.com/folder1/`

This is the content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?d2=$1&d3=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ secondindex.php?d2=$1&id3=$2&id4=$3  [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that for this type of links `https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/` it redirects ok to `https://www.example.com/folder1/index.php?d2=folder2&d3=folder3`, but for the second type of links it does not work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. based on your shown samples and attempts.

***Make sure to:***

- Place your .htacess file inside `folder1` folder.
- `index.php` and `secondindex.php` files also present inside `folder1`.
- Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /folder1/

##Internal rewrite for URL: https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ secondindex.php?d2=$1&d3=$2&d4=$3 [QSA,L]

##Internal rewrite rule for URL: https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?d2=$1&d3=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I get 404 error. Please note that the htaccess is in https://www.example.com/folder1/ , not in root, yes, I deleted the $1/ from beginning of index, please modify to access answer

Comment: @EvaDeka, I have **edited** my rules now. Please refresh this page and try newly edited rules and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: I will try with new code too, but also the first worked without the $1/

Comment: @EvaDeka, yes you are right, I have edited the code Just now, since your htaccess is inside folder1 we need to edit it a bit. Could you please try my edited code once and let me know how it goes, cheers.